# How do I kill the running app when I can't swipe upwards

Tags: iphone, multitasking

I launched an app on my iPhone, and shortly after launch it stopped doing anything; but whatever it did has stopped the swipe-up gesture from working, so I can't get to the application switcher to kill it.  I can use the side button to lock and unlock the phone, so I can get to the Lock Screen, and I can swipe down to get to the control centre, but no matter where or how much I swipe upwards the app just keeps running in the foreground.  I don't think the app has hung, because I'd have thought the OS would have killed it by now; it just sits there intercepting the swipes.

I have other things running in the background which I want to keep running, so I don't want to turn my phone off.  I've seen that there are accessibility settings which might help... but they're no good to me as I can't get to the settings app.

How do I kill the running app, without turning the phone off or changing any settings, when swiping up doesn't bring up the application switcher?

Comment: If you turn off the phone, the apps in the background will reload and continue normally.  If whatever app you’re using exhibits this behavior, the app is the problem, not iOS.

Comment: I'm assuming one of the Face ID phones rather than Touch ID? Do you have 'raise on wake' so you can see the lock screen? If so, from there you should be able to swipe up to launch something else - camera, shazam etc

Comment: @Allan I don't care whose fault it would be, I want to avoid it happening.

Comment: @Tetsujin: It's a Face ID phone, yes. I can get to the lock screen. The problem is that from there, I can swipe up to get to the faulty app, but that doesn't get me to the application switcher.  I can launch the camera or a few other things from the control centre, but I can't get to anything that's not already set up as a control centre button.

Comment: Can't you get to the app switcher once you're in camera? I'm not used to the no button phones, I sent mine straight back & got an SE instead, so I'm not familiar with the different swipe actions on those [one of the reasons I went back to a button phone]

Comment: @Tetsujin no.  You can access the camera from the lock screen, but if you swipe up from there it takes you back to the lock screen, not the application switcher - which makes sense, since at that point you haven't unlocked the phone.

Comment: I can do it on mine. Open camera. Quit camera. Unlock phone - camera is front-most app, from where the app switcher is now available.

Comment: Your iPhone may be configured into Single App Mode. Try pressing the side button three times and check if you see additional options.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think you're thinking of the Camera App, which you launch from Springboard, not the Camera controller which you can access from the lock screen.

Comment: @NimeshNeema nope - I get my usual accessibility menu, offering guided access, smart invert, VoiceOver, or zoom.

Comment: I've no idea what the difference might be. I can do this with anything I can launch from the control centre, though the response is slightly different. Wallet or Calculator open to the Springboard afterwards - no app frontmost. Camera opens to Camera after unlock. [Thinking about it, I don't think I've ever launched Camera from anywhere other than the lock screen]

Comment: @Tetsujin this must be a difference in Face ID vs Touch ID, or perhaps iOS versions.  In any case, I cannot get to the app switcher from any of them.

Comment: With power button switch off/on Lock Screen and wait the screen unlock, then open camera app from control center, then you can swipe up and see the app switcher : this is because the phone is unlocked. If you do not have the unlock icon the camera app is just sub app from Lock Screen.

Comment: @PtitXav that turns out not to be the case; see the conversation above.

Comment: @Simon : i made the test before answering. If you wait the Lock Screen to show the unlocked sign, when starting the camera from control center it will launch from the springboard.

Comment: @PtitXav possibly that's the case when you don't have an app which has failed in the way that mine did.  It didn't work when I had this problem - I still wasn't able to access the app switcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Siri enabled, you should be able to tell it to “Turn on VoiceControl” and then once that’s enabled, use your voice to tell your phone to “Open App Switcher” (voice control will always be listening for your voice to give it commands, you don’t need to activate Siri again)